Is there any way to explicitly trigger the fallback's execution if the msg.data matches an external function present in the contract?
I'm wondering whether there's a way to somehow explicitly trigger the fallback method, if the msg.data (calldataload, calldatasize and calldatacopy commands in Yul) already matches one of the functions declared in that contract.
For instance, I was wondering whether there's any potential exception case that would trigger the fallback instead, let's say given that the gas is too low to execute a normal call.
Is there anything like that in Solidity and the latest (Can-/)Dencun Ethereum upgrade?
My attempt was doing it that way, however the test didn't succeed, as the Storage contract still always calls the doSomething function by a direct match, not the fallback.
I need this for a proxy contract, and the proxy's doSomething matches exactly with the implementation's doSomething function, except for one difference: the _data argument is calldata in the proxy contract, and it's [bytes] memory [_data] in the implementation contract:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0

pragma solidity >=0.8.2 <0.9.0;

interface IFallbackeable {
    function doSomething(bytes memory _data) external payable returns(uint256);
}

contract Implementation {
    function doSomething(bytes memory _data) external payable {

    }
}

contract Fallbackeable {
    bool public fallbackCalled;
    Implementation public implementation = new Implementation();
    fallback() external payable {
        fallbackCalled = true;
        address contractLogic = address(implementation);
        assembly {
            calldatacopy(0x0, 0x0, calldatasize())
            let success := delegatecall(sub(gas(), 10000), contractLogic, 0x0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
            let retSz := returndatasize()
            returndatacopy(0, 0, retSz)
            switch success
            case 0 { revert(0, retSz) }
            default { return(0, retSz) }
        }
    }

    function doSomething(bytes calldata _data) external {
        address contractLogic = address(implementation);

        (bool success, bytes memory returnData) = contractLogic.delegatecall(
            abi.encodeWithSelector(implementation.doSomething.selector, _data)
        );

        require(success, string(returnData));
    }
}

/**
 * @title Storage
 * @dev Store & retrieve value in a variable
 * @custom:dev-run-script ./scripts/deploy_with_ethers.ts
 */
contract Storage {
    Fallbackeable public fallbackeable = new Fallbackeable();
    function testSigs() external payable returns (bytes memory sig, bool success, string memory messageStringified) {
        Implementation implementation = fallbackeable.implementation();

        sig = abi.encodeWithSelector(IFallbackeable.doSomething.selector, "hello!");

        bytes memory data;

        (success, data) = address(fallbackeable).call{value: msg.value}(sig);

        messageStringified = string(data);
    }
}


ANY suggestion is very welcome!!
